# Proper way to get the result of MySQL from Node.js function callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

What is the proper way to get the result of this MySQL Query out of GetAllFarms and into a variable called err and farms? Sorry, doing a quick code try and coming from a different language.

```
var err, farms = GetAllFarms()
console.log("GetAllFarms:")
console.log(farms)
console.log(err)


function GetAllFarms(callback) {
    query = db.query("SELECT * FROM farms ", function (err, result) {
        console.log("DEBUG:QUERY//");
        console.log(query.sql);
        // console.log(result)

        if (err) {
            // console.log(err)
            return callback(err, null)
        } else {
            // console.log(result)
            return callback(null, result)
        }
    });

    // db.end()

    console.log("query")
    console.log(query.result)

    return query
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decide wether you want to provide result via callback or with return. Don't mix them, it's confusable.

Callback approach

```js
var err, farms = GetAllFarms()
console.log("GetAllFarms:")
console.log(farms)
console.log(err)


function GetAllFarms(callback) {
    query = db.query("SELECT * FROM farms ", function (err, result) {
        console.log("DEBUG:QUERY//");
        console.log(query.sql);
        // console.log(result)

        if (err) {
            // console.log(err)
            return callback(err, null)
        } else {
            // console.log(result)
            return callback(null, result)
        }
    });

    // db.end()

    console.log("query")
    console.log(query.result)
}

// usage
GetAllFarms((error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      // handle error
    }
    // process result
})
```

Promise approach

```js
var err, farms = GetAllFarms()
console.log("GetAllFarms:")
console.log(farms)
console.log(err)


function GetAllFarms() {
    return new Promise((resolve, rejct) => {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM farms ", function (err, result) {
          console.log("DEBUG:QUERY//");
          console.log(query.sql);

          if (err) {
              return reject(err)
          } else {
              return resolve(result)
          }
      });
  });
}

// usage
(async () => {
  const res = await GetAllFarms();
  // or 
  GetAllFarms().then(/* ... */).catch(/* ... */);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. For the callback, what could be missing if the response was? TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: It seems that you didn't provided callback function as a first argument of function, I have added callback approach example in first code snipped, please take a look.

Comment: Also make sure that you provide callable function (like this `GetAllFarms(() => {})`) and not result of some function (like this `GetAllFarms(someFunc())`)